Opening an existing folder in a container throws an error
I've created a simple Deno app using Hono and successfully deployed to a Docker container using the following Dockerfile which is copied from docker.com
FROM denoland/deno:1.46.0

EXPOSE 1993

WORKDIR /app

USER deno

COPY deps.ts .
# RUN deno cache deps.ts

# These steps will be re-run upon each file change in your working directory:
COPY . .
# RUN deno cache main.ts

CMD ["run", "--allow-net", "main.ts"]

I've been trying to open this as a container in VS Code following this tutorial. The first error was that it did not recognise the deno cache command so I commented it out.
When I ran this again it choked on its own devcontainer.json config file. To fix this I deleted all the comment lines so it read.
{
    "name": "Existing Dockerfile",
    "build": {
        "context": "..",
        "dockerfile": "../Dockerfile"
    }
}

I now get the following error which I a struggling to resolve.
Command in container failed: mkdir -p '/home/deno/.vscode-server/bin' && ln -snf '/vscode/vscode-server/bin/linux-arm64/f1e16e1e6214d7c44d078b1f0607b2388f29d729' '/home/deno/.vscode-server/bin/f1e16e1e6214d7c44d078b1f0607b2388f29d729'

mkdir: cannot create directory '/home/deno': Permission denied

Has anyone else seen this error and is there a way to fix it?

I would consider the container you're deploying in and the container you're developing in two separate things. The former should be as slim and fast as possible, whereas the latter will contain more build tooling etc. Start from one of the base devcontainers images.

Thanks but not answering my question. This is my development container I'm trying to get to work, and which is throwing the error. I'm trying to figure out how to load my development container into VS Code.

Your Dockerfile doesn't look like it's suitable for dev containers - start from https://docs.deno.com/runtime/manual/references/vscode_deno/#using-a-development-container, which would lead to https://github.com/rsm-hcd/devcontainer-templates/tree/main/src/deno
